# How to display dialog box in OS X using Finder Sync Extension and Objective-C

Tags: xcode, osx-mountain-lion, finder, findersync

I am creating a cocoa application with finder sync extension. I'm trying to open dialog box on some events of finder app.I am beginner for x code and objective c. I have tried the below code on some event..

```
NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
    [alert setMessageText:@"Delete the record?"];
    [alert setInformativeText:@"Deleted records cannot be restored."];
    [alert setAlertStyle:NSWarningAlertStyle];
    if ([alert runModal] == NSAlertFirstButtonReturn) {
        // OK clicked, delete the record
    }
```

But this code is just for presenting alert box.
Can anyone suggest me how do I get dialog box.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with FinderSync. You need to learn some Mac UI. You need to define xib and nib, etc. You are jumping ahead too far.

Answer (score 1):

Try UIAlertView and UIAlertController or else simply use NSAppleScript

Comment: Thanks dass my question is for display dialog box to have full control since alert box only have OK and cancel buttons. I tried with some xib files to call over the event. Please let me know if there is anything else you can see for such a requirement.